# How many time Anonymous users are created in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to use the signInAnonymously feature from firebase but I'd like to know how it works exactly.

- Is this anonymous user added as any other user in Firebase (but without an email or password) ?
- Is it automatically removed after a certain time ?
- If I call this method on each app launch. Will it create a new user everytime ? How will it know how te reuse an old one ? Local Storage ?
- So will it create another user in database if my users connects from another device ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- An anonymous user account is similar to any other user account in Firebase, except that there is no way to identify the user.
- Anonymous users are not automatically removed.
- Each time you call the API to create an anonymous user, a new account will be created. To re-use the existing account, you should [listen for the auth state when the app starts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) and only create a new user account if the user isn't signed in yet.
- If the same (anonymous) user signs in from multiple devices, they will get a separate account on each. If that is not what you want for your use-case, you should require one of the identified authentication methods (email/password, Facebook, Google, etc)/

Answer (score 0):

Frank's answer to the third question is incorrect.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#signinanonymouslycompletion:):

> If there is already an anonymous user signed in, that user will be returned instead. If there is any other existing user signed in, that user will be signed out.

Therefore, this method can be safely called every time the application starts.